# Is there a way to know if a service worker has been terminated or restarted?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

We can't rely on global variables in a service worker, as the global state is wiped out each time the service worker is terminated (and eventually restarted).

How does one know when the service worker has been terminated? How does one know when it is restarted? There doesn't seem to be any lifecycle event that we can hook into.

What I'm looking for is something like `self.addEventListener('terminate', async () => {` and/or `self.addEventListener('restart', async () => {`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: [The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle), [Using Service Workers - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers), [ServiceWorkerGlobalScope: `activate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/activate_event)

Comment: @Andreas, the `activate` event does _not_ per se communicate _starting_ of a service worker; _activation_ is a different part of its life cycle. Not every starting of a service worker is activation, but every activation will naturally start one. Activation of a service worker is only done _once_ -- after it is installed and is no longer waiting [to be activated] as part of its containing registration. Stopping and starting of a service worker is done at the discretion of the user agent and isn't related to activation at all.